# What is this mystery volume in Windows 8.1?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, mount, defragment

What is this mysterious volume listed in Optimize Drives list in Windows 8.1? I only have one hard disk, drive C:.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: A screenshot from *Disk Management* could shed some light on this. To open *Disk Management* press Win+R and type `diskmgmt.msc`

Comment: Actually, you have one hard disk, which is divided into six partitions, of which one is labelled `C:` and you are asking about another. Oh, how much confusion could have been saved had Microsoft gone with a scheme that clarified the relationship between physical devices and partitions, back in the early 1980s...

Comment: Did the computer come with Windows 8 (and was later updated) or was Windows 8.1 a clean install?

Comment: @and31415 It came with Windows 8 and was later updated to 8.1.

Comment: Yeah, guessed that. Here's a related Microsoft forum thread which includes some explanation and possible solutions: [Strange new Drive created by Windows 8.1 update](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/40f23611-658c-47e8-abe4-ca2843d30228/strange-new-drive-created-by-windows-81-update?forum=w8itproinstall)